# thread sleeping cause the latency on UI loading

Tags: multithreading

i have a form that on its page load i need to work with peripherals ( serial port mainly ) , and i have to wait for proper response from serial port , so it takes a lot time to load the ui , is there any way to load the form while the peripheral functions are waiting for the response ?
my code is sth like this :

```
private Page_Load(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 port.Write("CMD1");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 if ( port.ReadExisting().Contains("CMD1OK"));
     port.Write("CMD2");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 if (port.ReadExisting().Contains("CMD2OK"))
    TaskDone();
 else
    TaskFailed();

}
```

As u can see in the code , because of thread sleeping the UI it takes time to load the form
its an idea to handle the port response by events , but i can do nothing about code sequence like , CMD2 above , to has to wait for the CMD1 response

Comment: No, this needs to work the other way around. Don't load the page until you got the response.  Never use Sleep() when you work with SerialPort, use the DataReceived event instead.

Comment: first i just need this information for this page so i just ask for them on this form load , second as u can see in the code CMD2 is sent only if the cmd1 successfully done , so i have to wait for the response